# Can not open csv file in JupyterLab

Tags: python

I'm getting a file not found error in JupyterLab. I can see the file and I have tried several different ways to open it via JupyterLab, but I keep getting an error as if the file does not exist.

Below is my code:

```
import os
import csv

csvpath = os.path.join('..','Resources','budget_data.csv')

with open(csvpath, newline="") as csvfile:
`enter code here`csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
```

### Here is the error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-3c32e2cc9d43> in <module>
----> 1 with open(csvpath, newline="") as csvfile:
 2     csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or  
directory: '..,Resources,budget_data.csv'
```

Here is the path:  GTATL201902DATA3/03-Python/Homework/Instructions/PyBank/Resources/budget_data.csv

Comment: Try to `print(os.path.abspath('.'))` before opening to check the current working dir.

Answer (score 0):

```
csvpath = os.path.join('..','Resources','budget_data.csv')
```

Are you absolutely sure this is the actual code you're using?  Because going by the error message, it looks like you did this instead:

```
csvpath = os.path.join('..,Resources,budget_data.csv')
```

i.e. the `..` and the commas are literally part of the string, instead of joining three separate strings.